# Add new fields to the FeatureLayer dynamically - arcgis JS API Version 4.7

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I've uploaded GeoJSON to Esri cloud and created a feature layer.  Now I'm able to plot the featurelayer into my map.  I'm trying to color each feature based on measures which comes from my DB.  Here is link to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vigneshncc/3oxcmq49/)

Let's say we are going to add a measure, i.e., Profit of the state Texas is 100.  So I'd like to add {'Profit':100} as a field to the Feature.

Here is the code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
  <title>Data-driven continuous color - 4.7</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.7/esri/css/main.css">
    <script>
    var dojoConfig = {
      has: {
        "esri-featurelayer-webgl": 1
      }
    }
  </script>
  <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.7/"></script>

  <style>
    html,
    body,
    #viewDiv {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>

  <script>
    require([
      "esri/Map",
      "esri/views/MapView",
      "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
      "esri/widgets/Legend",
      "esri/Graphic",
      "esri/tasks/support/Query",
  "esri/tasks/QueryTask",
      "dojo/domReady!"
    ], function(
      Map, MapView, FeatureLayer, Legend, Graphic, Query, QueryTask,
    ) {

      var defaultSym = {
        type: "simple-fill", // autocasts as new SimpleFillSymbol()
        outline: { // autocasts as new SimpleLineSymbol()
          color: "lightgray",
          width: 0.5
        }
      };

      var map = new Map({
        basemap: "streets"
      });

      var view = new MapView({
        container: "viewDiv",
        map: map,
        center: [-85.050200, 33.125524],
        zoom: 6
      });


    var openSpacesRenderer = {
        "type": "class-breaks",
        "field": "CENSUSAREA",
        "classBreakInfos": [
          {
            "symbol": {
              "color": [
                45,128,120,255
              ],
              "outline": {
                "width": 0
              },
              "type": "simple-fill",
              "style": "solid"
            },
            "label": "0 to 1,629",
            "minValue": 0,
            "maxValue": 100000
          },
          {
            "symbol": {
              "color": [
                173,212,106,255
              ],
              "outline": {
                "width": 0
              },
              "type": "simple-fill",
              "style": "solid"
            },
            "label": "> 1,629 to 3,754",
            "minValue": 100001,
            "maxValue": 200000
          },
          {
            "symbol": {
              "color": [
                226,235,211,255
              ],
              "outline": {
                "width": 0
              },
              "type": "simple-fill",
              "style": "solid"
            },
            "label": "> 3,754 to 11,438",
            "minValue": 200001,
            "maxValue": 1000000
          }
        ]
      }

      var featureLayer = new FeatureLayer({
        url: "https://services9.arcgis.com/JPp8avz1ETW9XJJr/arcgis/rest/services/USA_Outline/FeatureServer/0",
        outFields: ["*"],
        renderer: openSpacesRenderer
      });


      map.add(featureLayer);

      let graphics;

        view.when(featureLayer).then(function(layerView) {
        //debugger;
          layerView.watch("updating", function(value) {
            if (!value) { // wait for the layer view to finish updating 
              // query all the features available for drawing.
                  layerView.queryFeatures({
                    geometry: view.extent,
                    outFields: ["*"],
                    returnGeometry: true
                  }).then(function(results) { 
                    for(var r in results){
                        results[r].attributes['profit']= Math.random()*100
                        console.log(results[r].attributes);
                    }
                  }).catch(function(e) {
                    console.error("query failed: ", e);
                  });
            }
          });
        });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="viewDiv"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Now in the for loop I'm trying to add a attribute profit with what we have.  Then if I change field variable of openSpacesRenderer as profit, it is not working.  How can I add a new field to the existing feature layer?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `featureLayer`'s method [`applyEdits`](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-FeatureLayer.html#applyEdits)
EDIT: The `applyEdits` method is used to apply updates/additions and data deletion to a `FeatureLayer`. From the link above: If client-side features are added, removed or updated at runtime using applyEdits() then use queryFeatures() to return updated features.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Arcade expressions to calculatenew (temporary) fields, and then use them for popups and/or labeling.

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/guide/arcade/index.html
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/index.html?search=arcade

Comment: I think your answer would better if it included some sample code to do this rather than just links to where that might be found.